# Display records found by ActiveRelation in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-relation

I want to display the records returned by following line in html,

```
       @var = User.where("first_name like ?", "%"+params[:searchTextField]+"%")
```

How do i display these in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
<% @var.each do |v| %>
  <%= v.first_name %>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```